# How do I remove one svn:ignore rule?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, subversive, svnignore

Let's say I have a directory under SVN control and I have a LOT of svn:ignore rules defined for this directory. I want to remove only one of those rules. How can I achieve this?

I only found a command line solution to remove all rules, but this is not for me :)

PS: any solution will do: command line, eclipse, Tortoise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If tou are using TortoiseSVN you probably expect some graphical interface to do this, so:

> click Right Mouse Button on the directory you want to edit, then TortoiseSVN > Properties

And use the buttons and list there.

Comment: The GUI of Tortoise helped me to understand that there is only one rule for svn:ignore holding all file patterns to ignore. That's why I could not find a way to remove only one pattern. Only edit the whole list of patterns.

Answer (score 5):

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

will open an editor with all your rules.  Delete the one you don't want any more.  Save the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
svn propedit svn:ignore PATH
```

That will let you edit the value.  If you want the long version, you could:

```
svn propget svn:ignore PATH
```

Then create your own version, as you see fit, and then do an:

```
svn propset svn:ignore YOUR_NEW_VALUE PATH
```